# Python TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' error for POST method to receive data from android app

Tags: android, python, json, rest, flask

I am currently working with Python for my REST API which will be accessed by my android application. I have no problems with my GET method (my app can get the  JSON  data already) My problem is the  POST method.  With my code below, I am just wondering how to fix this? I'm a noob here and Ive been working on this for days already...I have tried it on Postman and tried it in  actual but it returns  a TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**' error. Whatpart of my code  triggered the  error?

**PYTHON code that's  supposed to handle POST requests:**

```
@app.route('/adduser', methods=['POST'])
def addnewuser():
    params = request.get_json()
    username = params["username"]
    password = params["password"]
    email = params["email"]
    bdate = params["bdate"]

    res = spcall("addnewuser",(username,password,email,bdate), True)
    if 'Error' in res[0][0]:
        return jsonify({'status': 'error', 'message': res[0][0]})
    return jsonify({'status': 'ok', 'message': res[0][0]})
```

**Android code for sending to  server:**
//wrote this on the onCreate method  as part of the Button layout:

```
JSONObject newuser = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    newuser.put("username", uname);
                    newuser.put("password", pword);
                    newuser.put("email", eadd);
                    newuser.put("bdate", bdate);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (newuser.length() > 0){
                    new JSONTask().execute(String.valueOf(newuser));
                }
```

**the JSONTask  class: from some tutorial on the net**

```
private static class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
        private static String JsonResponse,JsonDATA,inputLine;
        private static HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        private static BufferedReader reader;
        private static URL url;
        private static Writer writer;
        private static InputStream inputStream;
        private static StringBuffer buffer;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String...params){
            JsonResponse = null;
            JsonDATA = params[0];
            urlConnection = null;
            reader = null;
            try{
                //url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:5000/register");
                url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:5000/adduser");
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
                urlConnecew BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream(),"UTF-8"));
                writer.write(JsonDATA);
                writer.close();

                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if(inputStreation.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
                writer = nm == null){
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                while((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    buffer.append(inputLine).append("\n");

                if(buffer.length() == 0){
                    return null;
                }
                JsonResponse = buffer.toString();
                return JsonResponse;

            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                if(urlConnection != null){
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if(reader != null){
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    }catch (final IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your python(flask) code, it may work

```
if request.method == "POST":
        params = request.json
if request.method == "GET":
        params = request.args

username = params["username"]
password = params["password"]
email = params["email"]
bdate = params["bdate"]
```